# Facing issue while setting up Mysql with Keycloak [java.lang.Throwable: Lock owned during cleanup: ServerService Thread Pool -- 68]

Tags: keycloak, liquibase, rhel, keycloak-services, liquibase-hibernate

I'm setting up keycloak(in RHEL 9 Linux VM and version is rhsso-7.4.10) and mysql. Added the needed configuration changes in standalone.xml file but I'm getting below error.
The logs shows some lock owned during cleanup.
And I have even checked the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table in mysql[Id=1 LockGranted=null and LockedBy=null]

```
2023-08-22 13:24:50,561 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) IJ030022: Lock owned during cleanup: ServerService Thread Pool -- 68: java.lang.Throwable: Lock owned during cleanup: ServerService Thread Pool -- 68
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:978)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:575)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:761)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:700)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.queryServerVariable(NativeSession.java:597)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1394)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1387)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:677)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:183)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:103)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:341)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$$Lambda$825/348007722.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:678)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:133)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:59)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:67)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:157)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:148)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:97)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:244)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:185)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:147)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$$Lambda$763/650708196.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2818)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:369)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$712/1204989037.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$713/1047672027.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$713/1047672027.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$713/1047672027.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$713/1047672027.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

2023-08-22 13:24:50,809 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Database error during release lock: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@3ea2c6be
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1159)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService.releaseLock(CustomLockService.java:241)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$releaseLock$3(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:136)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:678)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.releaseLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:343)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:678)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:133)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:81)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:59)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:67)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:157)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:148)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:97)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:244)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:185)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:147)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2818)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:369)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@3ea2c6be
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:126)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1157)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@3ea2c6be
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:176)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:866)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    ... 65 more

2023-08-22 13:24:50,816 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Database error during release lock: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@c151482
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1159)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService.releaseLock(CustomLockService.java:241)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$releaseLock$3(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:136)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:678)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.releaseLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:149)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2818)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:369)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:309)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@c151482
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:126)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.commit(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1157)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@c151482
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:176)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:866)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    ... 46 more

2023-08-22 13:24:50,817 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:117)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:341)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
```

I have checked this https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1610353 solution from Redhat but I dont find any interleaving= true in properties. Can anyone please help.